# How can I count the number of caught exceptions in Java batch process?

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have a Java batch process which should print at the end of the process the number of exceptions caught in the Java application.

It's mandatory, because the client needs it.

I've found a solution but it seems that it can be optimized.

First I've created an int variable to count all errors caught.

```
int errors = 0;
```

Then, I've put a try/catch block to catch every Exception occurred inside the application by doing this:

```
       try{
          //My code goes here
          methodA(param1,param2,errors);
       } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            errors++;
       }
    
       if (errors > 0 ) {
         log.error(errors + " error(s) occurred in the application");
      }
```

And This is methodA , methodB and methodC :

```
    public void methodA(int param1, int param2, int errors){
       methodB(errors);
    }
    
    public void methodB(int errors){
       try{
         // using methodC result to do some other operations
         String text1 = methodC(errors); 
         // more code here
       }catch(Exception e){
         //another code here
         errors++;
       }
    }

  public int methodC(int errors){
       try{
         //Calculate a String in textReturned variable 
         return textReturned;
       }catch(Exception e){
         //another code here
         errors++;
         return "";
       }
    }
```

Everything works fine until here, but as you can see inside the `try` block I call `methodA(param1,param2, errors)` and `errors` should be inside the method in order to keep counting errors inside this method, and this method also call other methods such `methodB` and `methodC` (inside other classes). The problem is that I have to put `errors` inside every method call if I want to increment `errors` variable while catching any exception occurred across all the application.

Is there any better way to accomplish counting all caught Exceptions in the Java Application?

By the way, I'm working with Spring Batch 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use the try catch block in methodB instead use throw Exception method signature

```
public void methodA(int param1, int param2) throws Exception{
   methodB();
}

public void methodB() throws Exception{
   
     //code here
   
}
```

Because you are catching exception in the Calling method, that should have main error count logic. Not at the multiple places

```
 try{
      //My code goes here
      methodA(param1,param2);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        errors++;
   }

   if (errors > 0 ) {
     log.error(errors + " error(s) ocurred in the application");
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear at all. I've updated my question in order to explain it better. But I do this because I have some methods that should return a default value (such empty string in methodC) but also increment the errors variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment a counter in every `catch` block, I believe you can do that using Aspect Orientated Programming, specifically AspectJ's `handler` pointcut.

Spring's AOP does not offer the `handler` pointcut, but Spring does integrate with AspectJ.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj